# Find all critical points $f(x)=\cos x+\cosh x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, trigonometry

Find all critical points and say are they extremum points or not.

$$f(x)=\cos x +\cosh x$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\sinh x-\sin x$$

$\sinh x-\sin x=0$ for $x=0$ is true but how prove there are no other roots?

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\cosh x-\cos x$ if we proved that $x=0$ is only root then second question is see where second derivative is positive and negative but I can't do it can you help for this two questions?

Comment: $\cosh(x) >1\ge \cos(x)$ for $x\ne 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you your comment helped too.

Comment: You are welcome – I posted that comment as an answer as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x>0$, then\begin{align}\sinh(x)&=x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\\[6pt]&>x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}-\cdots\\[6pt]&=\sin(x).\end{align}And, if $x<0$, $\sinh(x)=-\sinh(-x)<-\sin(-x)=\sin(x)$. So, you only have $\sinh(x)=\sin(x)$ when $x=0$.

Now, it follows from the fact that $f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0$ and that $f^{(4)}(0)=2>0$ that $f$ has a minimum at $0$.

Comment: But that Taylor polynomials are around point $x=0$ it doesn't need proof why if around point $x=0$ holds then for points far from $0$ holds too?

Comment: The Taylor series of the $\sin$ function converges to $\sin(x)$ for *every* real number. The same thing occurs with the $\sinh$ function.

Answer (score 1):

For real $x \ne 0$ is $\cosh(x) > 1 \ge \cos(x)$, i.e. $f''(x) > 0$.

It follows that $f'$ is strictly increasing, so that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and strictly increasing on $[0, \infty)$.

Therefore $x=0$ is the only critical point of $f$, and it is a strict absolute minimum.

(Alternatively you can use that $f$ is strictly *convex*.)